# Multi-dimentional Array php condition loop and variable assignment

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

Need some help figuring this out. I have a JSON array going to a php file after the submit is clicked via ajax. Once decoded on the php side, it looks like this:

> Array
>
> ```
> [0] => Array
>     (
>         [ID] => 409
>         [ChangeType] => CHANGE_SEAT_TO
>         [Name] => John Doe
>         [Seat] => 
>         [setTo] => 4-2
>         [PreviousSeatValue] => 
>         [PreviousSeatNewValue] => Y
>     )
>
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [ID] => 278
>         [ChangeType] => CHANGE_SEAT_TO
>         [Name] => John Test
>         [Seat] => 4-1
>         [setTo] => 4-3
>         [PreviousSeatValue] => Y
>         [PreviousSeatNewValue] => Y
>     )
>
> [2] => Array
>     (
>         [ID] => 305
>         [ChangeType] => REMOVESEAT
>         [Name] => John Blue
>         [Seat] => 3-6
>         [setTo] => 0
>     )
>
> [3] => Array
>     (
>         [ID] => 314
>         [ChangeType] => CHANGE_SEAT_TO
>         [Name] => John Red
>         [Seat] => 3-4
>         [setTo] => 3-6
>         [PreviousSeatValue] => Y
>         [PreviousSeatNewValue] => Y
>     )
> ```

**Main Goal:**

What im trying to do is loop through all the arrays and if changetype matches a string("CHANGE_SEAT_TO" or "REMOVESEAT"), execute a SQL statement. Im having issues assigning variables to the different key values in the matching arrays during a loop. Here is what I have so far:

```
$obj = json_decode($_POST['myData'], TRUE);


foreach ($obj as $innerArray){
    foreach($innerArray as $key => $value){

        $$key = $value;
        if($value === "CHANGE_SEAT_TO"){
            echo $ID;
            echo $setTo;


        }
        if($value === "REMOVESEAT"){

            echo $ID;
            echo $setTo;


        }

    }

}
```

Now obviously this is set up for just testing purposes(i have the echo's displaying in the console log after successful ajax). With this setup, I am able to successfully echo out the ID of the matching elements but if I try any other one, the variable is undefined. Can anyone explain why this is happening and offer up a suggestion to the main goal? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only one `foreach()`, check the modified code

```
<?php
$obj = json_decode($_POST['myData'], TRUE);

foreach ($obj as $innerArray){
    if($innerArray['ChangeType'] == 'CHANGE_SEAT_TO') {
        // do stuff
        $id = $innerArray['ID'];
        // get rest of values in same way
    } else if($innerArray['ChangeType'] == 'REMOVESEAT') {
        // do stuff
        $id = $innerArray['ID'];
        // get rest of values in same way
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. Quick question though, that technique of using:

   foreach($innerArray as $key => $value){

       $$key = $value;}

how does this work? => $$key = $value;

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with ` $$key = $value;` ? Was that in a tutorial or something?

Comment: yes. About mid page:

http://willi.am/blog/2009/01/14/converting-php-associative-arrays-to-variables/

Comment: It creates variables with names as array element key and values as array element value, but this is not widely used, instead use something like this http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
foreach ($obj as $value) {
    if ($value['ChangeType'] == 'CHANGE_SEAT_TO') {
        echo $value['ID'];
        echo $value['setTo'];
    } elseif ($value['ChangeType'] == 'REMOVESEAT') {
        echo $value['ID'];
        echo $value['setTo'];
    }
}
```